# could we also calculate the number of permutations we have to do,to get the matrix $I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am given the matrix $$B= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 &0  & 1\\ 
 0& 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
1 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

and I want to find its order. So, I have to find the minimum $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $B^n=I$.

Instead of this way,could we also calculate the number of permutations we have to do,to get the matrix $I$?

Comment: Do you mean "number of transpositions"?

Answer (score 5):

Rather than the number of permutations, you have to compute the order of the permutation which corresponds to this matrix. The permutation in question is 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
3 & 4 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix},$$
which is the cycle $(1324)$, which has order $4$. Hence, the $n$ in question is $4$.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this would be to let the matrix act on the vector $\langle 1, 2, 3, 4 \rangle$, recognizing that the matrix will simply permute the entries of this vector.

When we let the matrix act on the vector once, we get the vector $\langle 4, 3, 1, 2 \rangle$.  The resulting permutation is a $4$-cycle in $S_4$, which has order $4$.  Therefore, $A^4 = I$.

---

Side note:

In general, if you are given the set $M$ of all $n \times n$ matrices whose rows are composed of the standard basis vectors $e_1, e_2, ..., e_n$, then there is an isomorphism $\phi:M \rightarrow S_n$.  See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) article.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial is:

$$p(\lambda)=\det(B-\lambda I)=\left| \begin{matrix}
-\lambda & 0 &0  & 1\\ 
 0& -\lambda & 1 &0 \\ 
1 &0  & -\lambda  &0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & -\lambda
\end{matrix}\right|=\lambda^4-1$$

So by [Cayley–Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem):

$$p(B)=0$$
$$B^4-I=0$$
$$B^4=I$$

Comment: As a matter of fact, the characteristic polynomial of a permutation matrix is closely linked to the cycle structure of the underlying permutation, so you don't have to compute this determinant and Jesko's answer is perfectly fine ;-)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I don't have idea of that relationship you have something to read about it?

Comment: I'll look for a better reference, but you may have a look at [this](http://ejp.ejpecp.org/article/viewFile/781/1019), section 2.2. I think I had an exercise on this, long ago.

Comment: Couldn't the order still be any divider of 4?

Comment: @IlikeSerena according with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem is the minimal polynomial which satisfies $P(A)=0$

Comment: @rlartiga: That is true for the minimal polynomial, but not necessarily for the characteristic polynomial. At this time we only know that the minimal polynomial divides the characteristic polynomial.